Html.HiddenFor assignment
I am trying to assign a value after the user clicks a button.  My element is initialized using Html.HiddenFor as follows.
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WirelessServices[Model.WirelessServices.IndexOf(line)].InitiatePort, new { id = (lineNumber + "_InitiatePort"), value = Model.WirelessServices[Model.WirelessServices.IndexOf(line)].InitiatePort, Name = (lineNumber + "_InitiatePort") })

After the user clicks the button a method is called to attempt to assign this using Javascript.  I cannot figure out how to assign the value in the function.  I need to change the value to "True" so that when I get back into the controller I can use the value.

Easiest option: open page in browser, inspect page, find hidden element, get its rendered ID, then use that.  As the id= will be dynamic (based on lineNumber) you might need to determine that value first.  Generally, dynamically generated IDs are a bad idea ("code smell") and there's probably a better way to do it, eg with relative DOM navigation as, using the ID, you'd have to find the dynamic id.   Can't provide much more without more specifics (eg surrounding HTML, where the button is etc).  But could be $(this).closest("form").find(".InitiatePort input:hidden").val("True")

Javascript works with the rendered html, so [edit]ing your question to include the rendered html would help greatly.

Off Topic: What's the type of lineNumber?  If it's a number (as implied) then you're generating id= and name= that may cause issues elsewhere.  See this answer

If the button is part of the "line" such as with a data table, ensure that it's click event handler has access to getting this line number. Typically that will mean having a "data-" attribute available. For instance:
assuming a for loop with a @lineNumber declared...
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.WirelessServices[Model.WirelessServices.IndexOf(line)].InitiatePort, new { id = (lineNumber + "_InitiatePort"), value = Model.WirelessServices[Model.WirelessServices.IndexOf(line)].InitiatePort, Name = (lineNumber + "_InitiatePort") })

<button type="button" data-line-number="@lineNumber" onclick="toggleLine">Toggle</button>

then in your handler:
function toggleLine(e){
   let $button = $(e.target);
   let lineNumber = $button.data('line-number');

   let $hidden = $(`#${lineNumber}_InitiatePort`);
   $hidden.val('{Updated Value}`);
}

Obviously with JS there are 1000 ways to skin the cat whether using JQuery, ES modules, etc. but that should hopefully that gives you some ideas to get it back on track.  I tend to prefer locating elements to update by ID rather than trying to locate them crawling the DOM. :)
